# github ssh gives permission denied

Tags: github, msysgit, ssh-keys

I have been trying to access github via ssh/msysgit.
Also I have followed each instruction of how to configure the ssh client, instruction by instruction. Still I got **permission denied**.

I use Windows 7.

```
$ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Henrik/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Henrik/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Henrik/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 D
n-5github2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5github2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/Henrik/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Henrik/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/Henrik/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/Henrik/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 4):

So your public and private keys are found, but the permission isn't granted.

That should be because you didn't correctly copied your public key to the GitHub Administration interface of your account, as explained in "[Deploy SSH keys](http://help.github.com/deploy-keys/)".

[image: deplay add ssh key]